# Weblogic Lock & Edit issue

Tags: weblogic12c

I am trying to edit some components in my weblogic, but after clicking on Lock & Edit button it is not at all allowing me to edit the components. It is keep on loading(for hrs) but not allowing to edit.

I tried with creating multiple domains also but i am facing the same issue.

I am not sure whether I have missed any config.
Can you please help as soon as possible?

Comment: What changes are you making? Have you tried making a single change, like log file size on the `servers-> <server name> -> logging` tab to see if you can activate it? Also - have you tried running in `Deployment Mode` rather than `Production` to see what happens?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there seems to be some issue with the package itself.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be similar to the following thread.

[Lock and Edit Button is Weblogic 12C admin console is not responding ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662121/lock-and-edit-button-is-weblogic-12c-admin-console-is-not-responding)

A thread dump would be needed to understand what "hangs".