# Lock and Edit Button is Weblogic 12C admin console is not responding ,

Tags: console, weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

Lock and Edit Button is Weblogic 12C admin console is not responding ,  when I click it it just keeps loading and nothing happens , I have tried Different Browsers with different cache settings nothing works. I want to make changes to the console . Is there any resolution?

This is a strange issue I could not find  answers for this anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Take a thread dump at the AdminServer JVM at the time it "hangs". To see what hangs exactly. If you are running inside an virtual Linux VM adding Java Option -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom might be worth to try.